# file type is not a valid win32 application

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have searched many related questions on various sites but found no solution for this variation of the problem.

I have a filetype (.vlm) located on a network drive, and the program I use to open it is installed on my Windows XP, SP3 computer. The file CAN be opened from inside the program, but if I navigate to the file through explorer and try to open, I receive the message that is it not a valid win32 application.

additional notes:

- I have already assigned the program to open all .vlms.
- I'm fairly certain the program is very old - 8-bit, since files can only be saved with no more than 8 characters. Ashlar DrawingBoard is the program.
- I know there is a simple fix, but I cannot find it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like your registry settings in `HKCR\.vlm` are wrong.

Comment: 8.3 file names have *nothing* to do with 8-bit software, not that XP would even support the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really .vlm or it is .vlm.exe Because this error occurs when a windows application is run having an invalid file format.

Goto folder options in windows explorer and uncheck the checkbox **hide file extension for known file types**

Now with this setting the file extension will be shown for all files and if the .exe appears then just rename it to .vlm